# Using Serenity Screenplay pattern waiting an element causes problems locating it

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

First of all i need to locate this element:

`<input aria-checked="false" id="input-190" role="switch" type="checkbox" aria-disabled="false" value="">`

so i have created this Target:

```
public class Page  {
      public static final Target SWITCH_INPUT = Target.the("switch input")
            .locatedBy("//input[@role='switch']")
            .waitingForNoMoreThan(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
}
```

and in another class need to locate this target and get the attribute `aria-checked`

```
var ariaChecked = actor.asksFor(Attribute.of(SWITCH_INPUT, "aria-checked"));
```

and here occurs something too odd to me, if i remove the `waitingForNoMoreThan(Duration.ofSeconds(20))` from my target definition, the actor can locate that target but by having the `waitingForNoMoreThan` in place, it returns empty string because the element is null.

Is this normal? I feel that the opposite is a legit scenario.

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you working on?

Comment: Sorry i can't because in order to access this page you need to login first. But the problem doesn't have to do with the element itself because i can locate it at least with no waiting. Apart from that i can confirm that the xpath is valid regardless the webdriver, i mean that typing this xpath in devtools can locate the desired element. Also this xpath returns a unique element

Comment: Maybe you need to scroll the page there since element is initially out of the visible area?

Comment: The strange thing is that without waiting I can locate it. What could have happened?

Comment: Well, I think I need to see your code and make actual debugging to answer here. I'm sorry..

Comment: Thanks @Prophet NP :) but i can't since it's from a private organization's code base

Comment: I understand, you already mentioned that. I just wanted to say unfortunately I'm not sure I can help in these circumstances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250433/discussion-between-ggeorge-and-prophet).